# RABL template with nil collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have the following RABL template file

```
node(:status) { response.status }
node(:errors)  { @errors.inspect }

collection :@substances
attributes :name
```

Now my controller action isn't actually invoked, because an authentication filter is running before hand and setting the return status to 401. So @substances is nil. RABL then fails with a

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

error. How can I get RABL to not start iterating over the collection when it's nil?

Comment: Didn't find a definitive solution to this. We've switched now to DHH's JBuilder, which has a nicer syntax and more possibilities imho.

Comment: I have had the same problem with "rabl-rails" and switched to "rabl". All works now fine..